# Laravel, как сделать взаимоотношения с условием

Tags: laravel

Есть две таблицы пользователей, одна для сайта, другая для телеграмм бота. Есть таблица операций. Хочу сделать выборку операций, как мне выбрать со взаимоотношениями. Т.е. если в таблице операции user_type == 0, то взаимоотношение с таблицей users, если user_type == 1 то с таблице telegram_users .

Answer (score 0):

Если не ошибаюсь это называется полиморфическое отношение. Можете почитать про это по данной ссылке https://laravel.com/docs/5.8/eloquent-relationships#polymorphic-relationships